# Filtering Arrays/Vectors in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, filter

I have two arrays in Matlab
say
A = [1 4 89 2 67 247 2]
B = [0 1 1 1 0 0 1]

I want an array C, which contains elements from array A, if there is 1 in B at the corresponding index. In this case, C = [4 89 2 2].

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
>> C = A(logical(B))

C =

     4    89     2     2
```